# Android Error 961 during install

Tags: android, installation

A user of my Android application called RouterCheck has reported receiving a 961 error during the installation. Going to Google, it isn't difficult to find info on how to solve this - mainly by clearing data and/or cache.

The app itself isn't big. The APK is under 3MB and it unzips into a bit over 6Mb.

So my question is: Have I as the app developer done anything to cause this problem, or is it really due to the state of the customer's phone? Is there anything I should do to help prevent future customers from getting the same problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No nothing is to be handled from the app side
 There is some problem in play store app and not in yours

Read this

Error code 961 appears when there is a misconfiguration of system files on the Google Play store. It is happening when downloading, updating and upgrading mobile applications for Android Operating System. To fix this issue, follow these steps. 
1. Go to settings 
2. Apps
 3. All and clear the cache
 4. Clear data for google play store
 5. Go to settings
 6. Accounts and sync
 7. Remove all the synced accounts
 8. Open google play and register your id again

If this won`t work, you could do reset for Google Play Store. Here how it do. 
1. Go to Setting 
2. Click Application or Apps 
3. Click Manage Application 
4. You will see downloaded, running, all, on SD card. 
5. Select All 
Q6. Choose Google service frame 
7. Choose force stop, 
8. Clear data.
 9. Restart. 
This will reset the Google Play Store and you can start downloading Apps as normal again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm a bit concerned about the phrase "a misconfiguration of system files". The new version of the app has only been live for a day and others have successfully installed it. Is the problem Google Play or the device itself?

Comment: As I said there will some misconfiguration issue in google play for a particular, following the steps in the answer will solve your problem